# Load pytorch model with correct args from files

Tags: pytorch, save, torch, bert-language-model, roberta-language-model

Having followed Chris McCormick's tutorial for creating a BERT Fake News Detector (link [here](https://mccormickml.com/2019/07/22/BERT-fine-tuning/)), at the end he saves the PyTorch model using the following code:

```py
output_dir = './model_save/'
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)
    
    
# Save a trained model, configuration and tokenizer using `save_pretrained()`.
# They can then be reloaded using `from_pretrained()`
model_to_save = model.module if hasattr(model, 'module') else model
model_to_save.save_pretrained(output_dir)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(output_dir)
```

As he says himself, it can be reloaded using `from_pretrained()`. Currently, what the code does is create an output directory with 6 files:

```
config.json
merges.txt
pytorch_model.bin
special_tokens_map.json
tokenizer_config.json
vocab.json
```

So how can I use the `from_pretrained()` method to load the model with all of its arguments and respective weights, and which files do I use from the six?

I understand that a model can be loaded as such (from [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html)):

```py
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

but how can I make use of the files in the output directory to do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this just feeding the model path to the from_pretrained() function.  The from_pretrained function was able to identify relevant json config files and load the model.  Like this:

```
TheModelClass.from_pretrained(output_dir)
```

Sometimes it helps to just try some code and see if it works.